# Ansible: How can I group multiple folders with paths in an Inventory file

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have five folders which have config files from different regions
I want to keep them under one group called region and run with each region name from the command line.
ex:

```
ansible-playbook script.yml region_name -k -K
```

How can I group the folders in Inventory file?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a region named `Foo` defined in your [inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html), you can limit the playbook to that using the `-l` or `--limit` parameter.

Inventory file (e.g. `hosts` in the current directory):

```
[Foo]
host1
host2

[Bar]
host3
host4
```

In your `group_vars` folder, you can then have one folder per group/region:

```
group_vars
  - Foo
    - regionvars.yml
  - Bar
    - regionvars.yml
```

Then when running the playbook, you can just run it for one region:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts -l Foo script.yml
```

Please refer to the documentation of the [ansible-playbook command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html) for more info.